# Bookmarking a form submit button

Tags: javascript, forms, function, if-statement

I have a form that, on submit, opens the pages the user checked in the form.
So the user checked, site1 and site2, on submit it would open those pages.

Now I want the users to be able to bookmark the submit button or something... 
Is there a way to do this. With a normal hyperlink you can just drag it but with a submit button this is not the case...

The bookmark still has to open the pages selected in the form.

My code:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="site1" name="site1" value="site1">Site1<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="site2" name="site2" value="site2">Site2<br>
<input name="submit" value="open it up!" type="submit" onclick="validate()">
</form>
```

The script so far:

```
function validate() {
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        var sitename = $(this).val();
        window.open('http://www.' + sitename + '.com');
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You could change the `input type=submit..` to a hyperlink and use css to style it as a button

Comment: You would also need to dynamically change its href attribute, rather than using an onclick/onsubmit handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution combine ideas from @Sthephen Muecke and @Dave:

```
html:
    <input type="checkbox" id="site1" name="site1" value="site1" onclick="changeSite(this);">Site1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="site2" name="site2" value="site2" onclick="changeSite(this);">Site2<br>
    <input name="submit" value="open it up!" type="button" onclick="validate()">
    <div id="newLink"></div>
```

js:

```
window.validate= function() {
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        var sitename = $(this).val();
        window.open('http://www.' + sitename + '.com');
    });
    return false;
}

window.changeSite= function(obj){
   var site = $(obj).val();
    $("#selectedSite").attr("href",site);
    $("#selectedSite").html(site);
    if($(obj).prop("checked")){
        $("<a/>",{
            id: site+"Test",
            href:site,
            html: site
        }).appendTo("#newLink");
    }
    else{
        $("#"+site + "Test").remove();
    }             
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WY7WN/15/)

Of course you can add a class to `<a>` element and appear as button:

[Link as button](http://jsfiddle.net/WY7WN/16/)

And when all checkboxes are checked open all sites:

[Open all sites when more than one checkbox is checked](http://jsfiddle.net/WY7WN/18/)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! But is there a way to combine all the buttons into one button. So if you check multiple boxes it creates one button that opens all of the pages?

Comment: I still have a few questions, but it takes long to answer them over this "chat" do you by any chance have skype or something. I feel like you can help me but I feel stupid having to keep asking here... Just skype chat is eneugh no voices needed..